# keeping header lines that begin with # using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a number of files I want to process. For each one, I want to remove any rows where the value in the 6th column is less than 50. I tried using: awk '($6 >= 50)'. However, this removes the header lines from the files, which I want to keep.

Each line of the header starts with a '#' symbol. So I need to modify the command so that it doesn't remove any lines that start with a #.

Comment: add `|| /^#/` to the end

Comment: @123 That works, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just say

```
awk '$1 ~ /^#/ || ($6>=50)' file
```

This tells `awk` to print lines that match either of these:

- First field starts with `#`. This way, leading spaces are overlooked, or
- 6th field is bigger or equal of 50.

Little test:

```
$ cat a
a1 2 3 4 5 52
a2 2 3 4 5 52
#a3 2 3 4 5 12
  #a4 2 3 4 5 12
a5 2 3 4 5 12
$ awk '$1 ~ /^#/ || ($6>=50)' a
a1 2 3 4 5 52
a2 2 3 4 5 52
#a3 2 3 4 5 12
  #a4 2 3 4 5 12
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the first pattern/action statement in your script should be

```
/^#/ { print; next }
```

The `next` statement causes awk to skip the remaining pattern/action combos and continue with the next line.